# Energy bounds (or the lack thereof) for a functional between almost Hermitian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Suppose that $(M,g,J_M)$ and $(N,h,J_N)$ are two almost Hermitian manifolds. For a differentiable function $f:M\to N$ define its pseudoholomorphic energy to be

$E_+(f)=\frac{1}{4}\int_M |Df+J_N Df J_M|^2dV_g$

The name comes from the fact that if $E_+(f)=0$ then $f$ is pseudoholomorphic in the sense that $J_N Df=Df J_M$. Many authors (Lichnerowicz is one of the earliest I know of) have considered this energy in the context of $N$ being almost-Kahler ($d\omega_N=0$) and $M$ being balanced ($d^*\omega_M=0$) where it differs from the Dirichlet energy $E(f)=\frac{1}{2}\int_M|Df|^2dV_g$ by a constant depending on the homotopy class of $f$. The Dirichlet energy is THE energy you need to control when analyzing $f$ to apply various estimates and get compactness/convergence results. I've always wanted to apply $E_+$ in non-Kahler settings. So here is a question.

---

Find a compact Riemann surface $(\Sigma,g,J)$, a compact almost Hermitian $(N,h,J_N)$, and a sequence of maps $f_n:\Sigma\to N$ such that the $f_n$ are homotopic to each other, $E_+(f_n)$ is bounded but $E(f_n)\to\infty$.

---

Necessarily $N$ must be non-Kahler. In fact $h$ can't be bounded above and below by a Kahler metric, because I can show $E$ is bounded in that case. The most fruitful situation that might work (I'm here because I have trouble with the details) is the following.

Let $N$ be an Inoue surface. Then $N$ is a three torus bundle over the circle with the property that it has no nontrivial closed complex submanifolds. If you look at the tangent space there is an integrable 2D distribution of complex planes whose leaves are dense in each three torus fiber.

So take some non-trivial two torus in $N$ which is "almost holomorphic" in the sense that it is tangent to this distribution outside some small ball. Flow by the negative gradient of $E_+$ to get a family of torii which are "more holomorphic" over time. Since the distribution is dense and $N$ has no closed complex submanifolds, I expect this flow to "spaghettify" the torus, stretching it out to have more and more Dirichlet energy while $E_+$ gets smaller over time.